# How to find a more complex specific node by ancestor, parent and child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, nodes

This is a stripped down version of my XML file `simple.xml`.

```
<Genealogy> 
  <grandParent> 
    <name>bob</name> 
    <surname>Carter</surname>
    <Parent>
      <tel_Number>0033689765498</tel_Number> 
      <mobile_Phone>2</mobile_Phone>
    </Parent>
  </grandParent>
  <grandParent> 
     <name>jean</name> 
     <surname>Wright</surname>
     <Parent>
      <tel_Number>0033648245432</tel_Number> 
      <mobile_Phone>1</mobile_Phone>
     </Parent>
  </grandParent>
</Genealogy>
```

Using an Xpath expression, is it possible without looping over all nodes to find the correct/specific node `//grandParent/Parent` whose properties are for example:

```
Parent                       child of       grandParent
  tel_Number="0033648245432"                   name="jean"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an XPath expression like this:

```
//grandParent/Parent/tel_Number[text()='0033648245434' and ../../name/text()='jean']
```

with code like this:

```
name  = "jean"
phone = "0033648245434"

Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.load "C:\path\to\simple.xml"

expr = "//grandParent/Parent/tel_Number[text()='" & phone _
       & "' and ../../name/text()='" & name & "']"

Set nodes = xml.selectNodes(expr)

For n In nodes
  WScript.Echo n.parentNode.nodeName
Next
```